# Generics with wildcard not compiling

Tags: java, generics, interface, wildcard

The following code is not compiling:

```
public class Example {

    public void method() {
        Callback<BaseResponse> br = null;
        Request<? extends BaseResponse> req = null;
        req.startRequest(br); //compile-time error here!!
    }

    public interface Callback<T> {
        void onResponse (T response);
        void onFailure (String error, int code);
        void onFailure (Throwable t);
    }

    public static class BaseResponse {
        public String status;
    }

    public interface Request<BaseResponse> {
        void startRequest(Callback<BaseResponse> callback);
    }
}
```

If I take away the `? extends` part then the code compiles, but I need it in. I can't understand why is it not compiling? Looks perfectly "type safe" to me.

What workarounds or design changes should I make to get this to work?

Comment: We're supposed to ignore the `NullPointerException` that will be thrown? Can you include some actual code?

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to dereference a variable on the line after you set it to null.

Comment: @DimaSan, OP says explicitly _If I take away the ? extends part then the code compiles, but I need it in._

Comment: @SeanBright sure, didn't notice that, thanks for remark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is on the line

```
public interface Request<BaseResponse> {
```

where you've made `BaseResponse` a type parameter, and effectively hidden the class of the same name.  You probably meant to write

```
public interface Request<T extends BaseResponse> {
```

or something similar.

Comment: This worked amazingly. I actually have `T extends BaseResponse` in my real code but it gave me compile time error. I think this was actually caused by some bug in NetBeans.

The error was `incompatible types: Callback<BaseResponse> cannot be converted to Callback<CAP#1>
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends BaseResponse from capture of ? extends BaseResponse`

Comment: That is not a bug in NetBeans. Never blame the tools for the quality of the work. Wildcard generics are no good for a variable declaration because there is no way to tell what type is intended. `?` means "unknown type", and it should be obvious that that won't work as a type declaration. The capture failure is similar; your code that you did not share tried to equate "unknown type" with a specific type, and no way the compiler can validate that.